What is "clall" in index.Gap in "clusterSim" R package?
I am using the "clusterSim" package in my project (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clusterSim/clusterSim.pdf, page 39) and I do not understand the meaning of the "clall" variable and why, in the example 1 of documentation, the pam algorithm is used twice and saved in two different variables.
Could someone explain to me?

This will probably be closed for being off topic but
clall is, as the documentation says:

Two vectors of integers indicating the cluster to which each object is
allocated in partition of n objects into u, and u+1 clusters

and pam is called twice to give two solutions, one with 4 clusters and one with 5.
